# how to implement movement in gdscript when using rigid bodies?

Tags: godot, gdscript

so I got this thing from a tutorial, switched the default meshes and tried to add some animations, I'm used to work with kinematic bodies and not rigid bodies, but this has better camera to movement controls. took me some time to understand how to fix the jumping bugs that came with this project and now i'm trying to add movement to the attacks and I'm in a pickle because the character either attacks or moves.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to make it so that when you press left click, the attack keybind, the animation plays and the character moves in the direction that it is rotated.

what I have accomplished so far was either getting the left click to move the character but no animation plays or getting the lef click to play the animation but no movement happens or the movement doesn't follow the correct direction.

```
    #inputs
    dire.x = -Input.get_action_strength("A")+Input.get_action_strength("D")
    dire.z = -Input.get_action_strength("W")+Input.get_action_strength("S")
    rota = camera.global_transform.basis.get_euler().y
    dire = dire.normalized().rotated(Vector3.UP,rota)
    
    #state machine
    match state:
        "move":
            state_move()

func state_move():
    
    #run/strafe speed
    var spd_cap = mspd
    var jmp_cap = jspd
    
    #sprint
    if Input.is_action_pressed("SHIFT") && !Input.is_action_pressed("RMB"):
        spd_cap = mspd*1.4
        jmp_cap = jspd*1.2
    
    #move+moving platforms
    physics_material_override.friction = 1-dire.length()
    linear_velocity.x = lerp(linear_velocity.x,dire.x*spd_cap,accel)
    linear_velocity.z = lerp(linear_velocity.z,dire.z*spd_cap,accel)
    
    #jump
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("SPACE"):
        if grounded == true and isOnFloor== true:
            linear_velocity.y = jmp_cap
    if Input.is_action_just_released("SPACE"):
        if linear_velocity.y > 0:
            linear_velocity.y /= 2
    #Attacking but movement doesn't work        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("LMB"):
        linear_velocity.z = lerp(linear_velocity.z,dire.z*mspd,accel)
    #animation
    if Input.is_action_pressed("RMB"):
        player.rotation.y = lerp_angle(player.rotation.y,rota,0.1)
    elif dire != Vector3.ZERO:
        player.rotation.y = lerp_angle(player.rotation.y,atan2(-dire.x,-dire.z),0.1)
    get_node("CollisionShape").disabled = false
    visible = true
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("W") or Input.is_action_pressed("S") or Input.is_action_pressed("A") or Input.is_action_pressed("D") and isOnFloor:
        setStateWalk()
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("LMB") and isOnFloor:
        setStateAttack()
    else:
        setStateIdle()
```

Comment: This is a cross post (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/205947/movement-with-rigidbodies-doesnt-work-godot) - please pick one site.